# Python app to serve a webpage and detect when someone visits it?

Tags: python, web, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a way to write a small python app (ubuntu) which will serve a simple webpage on port 80 for example but also will detect when someone load it (visits it). I want to raise a certain event upon visiting and execute another function which will send some information to an external device.

An yes, I'm new to python. I do have a script for just serving a page, but can't get a part into it to raise the event of visiting this page:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Thank you for you help!)

p.s. In total it's a "physical" counter..so to say:) I have it all running on Raspberry Pi and want to light up leds upon visitors viewing the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "raising an event"? What sort of event? Pop up a dialog? Call some random function? Send a hardware interrupt? Write to a log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried something as simple as:

```
...
def get(self):
    self.write("Hello, world")
    light_the_leds()
...
```

All you have to do is write the `light_the_leds` function. Or is "how do I write the `light_the_leds` function" what you're really asking?

Comment: No no no:) I know how to light up the leds:) sorry for confusion:) i was abit off on a subject of "where is this event of loading page"?:) where i can hook up the light_the_leds functions. will give it a try:)